# How to add a List Button on a listview

Tags: ios, uitableview, listview

I want to add an Option buttion to a listview.

Currently I am following **[ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)**

this tutorial to populate the list. Now It will show the list correctly. Now I want to add an Option button on this list Item.

While tap on that Button I need to display a list with 3 option. Now I had added a UIButton on my `UITableViewCell` page and it will display on the List also.

How can I populate an option list on this button click?

Comment: you can try delegates

Comment: Can u show me an example

Comment: post your button action code

Comment: Now I have added only button on the  UITableViewCell. Now I want to populate a list on that button click. I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of button I'm giving you you an example on tableViewCell Clicked

In your TableVC

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   DestinationViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationVC"];
        controller.delegate = self;

        _popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:controller];
        _popOverController.delegate = self;

        [_popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect){point, CGSizeMake(0,0 )} inView:[self view]  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];

}
```

Make a DestinationVc and populate it.
:)